# Javascript quick variable assignment

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, variable-assignment

This is one of those questions I don't know how to properly word so I appologize if it has been asked before.

Python provides some very simple statements for quickly assigning arrays to values. For example if I have a box as an array like so `box=[0,0,100,100]` I can assign those points like so `x1,y1,x2,y2=box`. Is there such a statement in javascript? This would be especially useful in class functions where `var x1,y1,x2,y2=this.box` would be much less verbose than

```
var x1=this.box[0];
var y1=this.box[1];
var x2=this.box[2];
var y2=this.box[3];
```

If so, then are there any javascript methods that apply this to for loops? Coming from python, the below just seems so intuitive

boxes=[[0,0,100,100],[0,0,100,100],[0,0,100,100],[0,0,100,100]]

```
for box in boxes:
 x1,x2,x3,x4 = box
 #do something
```

definitely more intuitive than

```
var boxes=[[0,0,100,100],[0,0,100,100],[0,0,100,100],[0,0,100,100]];

    for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length : i++){
      var box = boxes[i];
      var x1 = box[0];
      var y1 = box[1];
      var x2 = box[2];
      var y2 = box[3];
```

Comment: PHP (`list`) and Perl have it too. Javascript doesn't.

Comment: FYI its call destructured assignment and in in js 1.7 (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New%5Fin%5FJavaScript%5F1.7#Destructuring%5Fassignment)

Comment: @Alex: Thanks. It's, in my opinion, not as clean as in Python, but it definitely helps

Comment: @Alex, another example is default values. I really could use default values in function parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cross browser it isn't possible, sorry.  Firefox implements a new syntax, but no other browser currently does:

```
var [x, y] = [1, 2];
```

Comment: This is new javascript syntax, as far as I know 1.7. Sadly the support isn't available.

Comment: Such a pitty, this is one of the cases where I don't think JS has made a good design decision

Comment: Note that plenty of people rave about coffeescript: http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/, which compiles down to JS.  It supports the above syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that's a no go.. Alternatively, you could generate your list as

```
var boxes = [
   {'x1':0, 'y1':0, 'x2':100, 'y2':100},
   {'x1':0, 'y1':0, 'x2':100, 'y2':100},
   {'x1':0, 'y1':0, 'x2':100, 'y2':100},
]
```

Then you can access them with

```
for (i in boxes) {
   var box = boxes[i]
   // use box.x1 box.y1 box.x2 box.y2
   //such as:
   console.log(box.x1);
}
```